# Entity Creation in Linq-to-SQL Classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql

How many entities we can create in Linq-to-SQL Classes(Per .dbml file)?

I have 1,500 tables in my database.

While executing application in Linq-to-SQL Classes, it's showing

> Not Enough storage space

Comment: Based on Sergi's answer, are you getting this error when you try to run a query, or when you try to create entities from your database tables?

Answer (score 1):

There's no limit on how many entities can be created from your database.  You might just be running out of memory in Visual Studio.

**Edit**

Based on Anton's comment, try restarting Visual Studio.  Failing that, you may have to break up your data model into multiple dbmls with your various tables distributed throughout.

Comment: yes, there is no limit but there is problem with out of memory. I have about 200 tables and sometimes when I build project I got error "out of memory". It disappears only after restarting VS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's, quite literally, not enough space in de database to store any more entities. Is your HD full? Did you set a maximum size for your database file?

Answer (score 0):

Try using sqlmetal via the command line instead of Visual Studio to generate your classes - it could be VS.NET is using too much memory.